# best way of processing large number of images for flash gallery?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

wondering what the most ideal way would be for loading a large number of images into Flash dynamically?

I was originally thinking of a simple serverside script to pass a comma delimitered list of images via sendAndLoad -  however I could be dealing with 100+ images of vary file name length so assume I could hit the sendAndLoad limit

```
&images=photo.jpg,photo.jpg,photo.jpg,photo.jpg,photo.jpg,photo.jpg
```

The second thought was to use sendAnLoad to call a serverside script to generate a serise of XML files to then in turn load when a "next page" button was pressed in Flash

```
&pagedata=page1.xml
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My vote for **xml**.

This will give you ability not only pass more pictures url to the app, but also include additional configuration/information, like picture name, author, date, comments...etc.